# Signing new key with an old expired one

Tags: gpg

I missed expiration date of my `gpg` key and have to generate a new one afterwards. Now I want to establish trust between my old and new key.

Naive call like

```
gpg --local-user DE5A457C --sign-key BCBE2B4A
```

ends in error message

```
gpg: skipped "DE5A457C": unusable secret key
```

How do I force `gpg` to sign a new key with an old, expired one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you can that, it's kind of violating the point of setting an expiry date. But you can probably trick `gpg` by running it in some kind of virtual machine that allows you to set the time to shortly before the old key expired. I don't know if gpg will let you sign a key that's not yet valid, but then you'll just have to make a new new key in that virtual machine and use that instead of `BCBE2B4A`.

Comment: It was my first thought too, setting the system time back. But I throw it away as dirties hack ever for such a problem.
I understand, that signing with an expired key is violation of concept. But now I clearly have need to do it so. It shouldn't be easy and demand some extra flags like --it-shit-but-do-it-so-

Comment: The expiry of a key can be arbitrarily changed using `gpg --edit-key`. No need for hacks.